# Undefined reference to several OpenMP functions

Tags: openmp

I was trying to compile an openMP example and he refuses to compile saying "undefined reference to 'OSCR_init', undefined reference to `OSCR_getarg_int' and several other functions. Then I located these functions in the file OmpSCR.h, that came in another folder, searched inside it and saw that these funcions were defined externally, I believe that in omp.h. I included the file with "include " in the example source (OmpSCR.h was already included) hoping that it would solve the question, but nothing improved. I do have omp.h, it came with the os. Can it be a version conflict? I got the example file from OMPSCR_v2.0.tar.gz What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An "undefined reference" error means that no definition of the function was found at link time.  A declaration in a header (such as `omp.h`) doesn't provide an implementation for the function; it just tells the compiler that the function exists *somewhere*.  You have to link your program with a library that actually provides the function's implementation.

Basically, you just need to link your program to an OpenMP library.  The way to do this depends on which compiler and which OpenMP implementation you're using, neither of which you've specified, so I can't provide specifics.  (But if you happen to be using GCC, you should use the `-fopenmp` option for both compiling and linking.)

Comment: I am using -fopenmp with gcc and it is not working. There is a libgomp.so library. I don't know if these functions are there. What can I do now?

Comment: You shouldn't need anything besides `-fopenmp`; in particular, you don't need to explicitly link with `libgomp.so` (it's implied by `-fopenmp`).  If you're compiling and linking in separate steps, make sure you're using `-fopenmp` for *both*.